# getting data from postgresql for one week

Tags: postgresql

Trying to get data for one week from the DB but it does not work, when I try for one day it works fine here is my one day script that works fine:

```
WHERE start_stamp at time zone 'America/New_York' >= TIMESTAMP 'yesterday'::timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York'
and start_stamp at time zone 'America/New_York' <  TIMESTAMP 'today'::timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York'
```

and here is my one-week scrip that does not work:

`WHERE time > now () - interval '1 week';`

here is the error message I have got

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"

not sure if this is the right statement but I posted one of what I have tried so far.

Comment: In what client are you running this?

Comment: `time` is a Postgres keyword.  Is that really the name of your field?

Comment: Ardrian, I am just using Linux.  Tim I really dont understand your question, am new to this psql db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this :

```
select ...
from tablename
where start_stamp at time zone 'America/New_York' >= now() at time zone 'America/New_York' 
  and start_stamp at time zone 'America/New_York' < now() at time zone 'America/New_York' - interval '1 week';
```

alternatively you can use `between` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got working with WHERE start_stamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '7 days')